# Windows 8.1 command like Unix/Linux WHICH command

Tags: windows, command-line, python

Below is an example of the results of the **WHERE** command used in Win 8.1 CMD

`(DJANGO) C:\Python34>where python
C:\Python34\python.exe
C:\Python34\DJANGO\Scripts\python.EXE`

What I am looking for is something that would return only **WHICH** version/insistence would run. In this case I would expect to only see `C:\Python34\DJANGO\Scripts\python.EXE` since I had a virtualenv activated.

Comment: [Is there an equivalent of 'which' on the Windows command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/304319)

Comment: Try typing this at a PowerShell prompt. I'm not sure if it will behave exactly as expected but should be close:
`[IO.Path]::GetFullPath("python")`
If this does what you want I can write a function to make it easier to use.

Comment: '[IO.Path]::GetFullPath("python")' did not work. **WHERE** simply follows the environment variable _PATH_ breadcrumb trail and reports as encountered, regardless if the virtualenv is activated or not.

Answer (score 0):

To only get one result, you can filter the output of where to get only the first match

```
where python |cmd /v /c"set/p.=&&echo(!.!"
```

But from the sample you posted, you will not get the output you want. You are asking windows and in windows, the current active directory will be the first place to search for a file. So, if your current active folder contains the executable you are searching (your case) it will be the called one.